# nginx @rewrites for directory - not working?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm playing around with Nginx and installed a cms system that needs rewrites, the normal code would be:

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites; }

location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?page=$1&id=$2&subpage=$3 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 last;
}
```

But this CMS i installed in a different directory called  testcms. So i thought this would work:

```
location /testcms {

fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
fastcgi_index index.php;

try_files $uri $uri/ /testcms@rewrites;

}

location /testcms@rewrites {
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /testcms/index.php?page=$1&id=$2&subpage=$3 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /testcms/index.php?page=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ /testcms/index.php?page=$1 last;
}
```

but this results in a white page and no error in the nginx log.
Any idee what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error. Should be something like

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;

}

location @rewrites {
```

From the Nginx [manual](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> The prefix "@" specifies a named location. Such locations are not used during normal processing of requests, they are intended only to process internally redirected requests

Comment: mmh thx! i tried it.. but still i have a white screen the homepage/ index.php page works, but then when i go to index/login  it shows a white empty screen, if i got to /testcms/index.php?page=login it shows the login page..  I will try some other settings

Comment: It seems as if it doesn't get the "$1" because if i server to /testcms/index.php?page=    with nothing.. it  has a simular pages(nothing)